# Apple Login Custom Button

Tags: ios, swift

i will apply the Apple Login Service in my App. so i used ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.

but because this button's text size(about 18 ~ 19 font) is so big(button height is 48), i have chosen to use a custom Apple Login Button(Left-Aligned Logo Buttons) for this [page](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/)

in my custom Apple Login Button, 
can i set the text size to 15pt font?(a little bit smaller than ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton text size)

is there any problem in apple store review?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/#creating-a-custom-sign-in-with-apple-button):

> Specifically, the title's font size should be 43% of the button's height - in other words, the button's height should be 233% of the title's font size, rounded to the nearest integer [...]

Therefore if you want to set **15pt** font, you need to set the **height of the button to 35pt**.

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the Font that Apple uses in their `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` I have found that the ratio is 17 : 44. Or, equally, font size is ~38% of the button's height. /shrug